# cannot find module 'google-module'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions, particle.io

I'm excited to get started with the Particle Electron logging GPS coordinates and storing them up in the Google Cloud Platform.  I have all the integrations connected using this tutorial, https://docs.particle.io/tutorials/integrations/google-cloud-platform/  l and am now getting this error trying to run the script using the instructions here:  https://github.com/particle-iot/google-cloud-datastore-tutorial   running the script gives me this error:

```
@electronmapper-1521735511351:~/google-cloud-datastore-tutorial$ node tutorial.js
Authenticating with Google Cloud...
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'google-cloud'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/michael_przekaza_ii/google-cloud-datastore-tutorial/tutorial.js:13:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
@electronmapper-1521735511351:~/google-cloud-datastore-tutorial$
```

Do you know what a module.js: 540 error is? npm updates have been unsuccessful. I've also installed dependencies.  I believe I have the correct Setup Configuration. Any help would be awesome! Thanks in advance.  -MP

Comment: This is using an older google-cloud library version. Does it work if you try with the newest library? In package.json change `"^0.40.0"` to `">=0.40.0"` and run npm updates again.

Comment: looks like npm was able to add the dependencies. I can now run the script but am now getting:Auth error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0
Auth error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0
Auth error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0 ...... this keeps scrolling. any suggestions? Does it have to do with my particle microcontroller not online?

Comment: Double check your `gcp_private_key.json` for errors/typos.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this AuthError by updating the gcp_private_key.json file?

Comment: Thanks guys, yes I've been able to solve my AuthError issue. I am now trying to confirm my data is being stored in the cloud but am now getting a "RESOURCE NOT FOUND" error when running  the command: gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull electronMapperPUBSUBtopic --auto-ack . Any thoughts?